# How to decrease Oracle undo tablespace in AWS RDS?

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, tablespace

Undo tablespace in my Oracle DB is taking 180GB. I don't have any process that would need this much space. There was an unknown issue with the DB, which cussed the undo table size to increase back in a while; and after bouncing RDS instance it has been rectified. The issue now is how decrease the size of the undo tablespace. I have managed to create a new undo table using

```
creat undo tablespace UNDO_T2;
```

but have failed to tell oracle to use the new undo table space. Here is my query and its error:

```
alter system set undo_tablespace = UNDO_T2;

Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02065: illegal option for ALTER SYSTEM
02065. 00000 - "illegal option for ALTER SYSTEM"
*Cause: The option specified for ALTER SYSTEM is not supported
*Action: refer to the user manual for option supported
```

Comment: pretty sure a hardore way would be to set up a new instance the way you want - then EXP from the old and IMP to the new.

Comment: Added a datafile to the undo_t2 tablespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully resize the UNDO table down to 16GB using the following command. This requires Master User permission for the RDS instance.

ALTER TABLESPACE UNDO_T1 RESIZE 16G;

One should check what is a suitable size for there Oracle instance.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the [command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10595/undo005.htm#i1106407), with an extra `e`. Unless you have a weird tablespace name you don't need the quotes either.

```
alter system set undo_tablespacee = 'UNDO_T2';
```

... should be:

```
alter system set undo_tablespace = UNDO_T2;
```

Comment: Sorry it’s just a typo when writing the question. I verified that right version has been tried.

Comment: If you're asking for help with an error from a comand, don't you think it would be sensible to cut-and-paste exactly what you did and what response you got? How are we supposed to guess what you did wrong if we don't know what you actually did?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a datafile to this tablespace?

Comment: Sorry it’s just a typo when writing the question. I verified that right version has been tried.